# Informatica session refuses to update first then insert in "update then insert" mode

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Very basic setup: source-to-target - wanted to replicate the MERGE behavior.
Removed the update strategy, activated "update then insert" rule on target within the session. Doesn't work as described, always attempts to insert into the primary key column, even though the same key arrives, which should have triggered an "update" statement. Tried other target methods - always attempts to insert. Attached is the mapping pic.

[basic merge attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnbiD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out. You have to make edits in 3 places: a) mapping - remove update strategy b) session::target properties - set the "update then insert" method c) session's own properties - "treat source rows as"

In the third case you have to switch "treat source rows as" from insert to update.
Which will then allow both - updates and inserts.

Why is it set like this is beyond me. But it works.

Comment: Did you try to set the flag for update strategy. If you set it then you dont need to select the update else insert. I believe you did both , thats why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make an attempt to clarify this a bit.

First of all, using `Update Strategy` in the mapping requires the session `Treat source rows as` property to be set to `Data driven`. This is slowest possible option as it means it will be set on row-by-row basis within the mapping - but that's exactly what you need if using the `Update Strategy` transformation. So in order to mirror MERGE, you need to remove it.

And tell the session not to expect this in the mapping anymore - so the property needs to be set to one of the remaining ones. There are two options:

- set `Treat source rows as` to `Insert` - this means all the rows will be inserted each time. If there are no errors (e.g. caused by unique index), the data will be multiplied. In order to mimic MERGE behavior, you'd need to add the unique index that would prevent inserts and tell the target connector to `insert else update`. This way in case the insert fails it will make an update attempt.
- set `Treat source rows as` to `Update` - now this will tell PowerCenter to try updates for each and every input row. Now, using `update else insert` will cause that in case of failure (i.e. no row to update) there will be no error - instead an insert attempt will be made. Here there's no need for unique index. That's one difference.

Additional difference - although both solutions will reflect the MERGE operation - might be observed in performance. In the environment where new data is very rare, the first approach will be slow: each time an insert attempt will be made just to fail and do an update operation then. Just a few times it will succeed at first attempt. Second approach will be faster: updates will succeed most of the time and just on a rare occasion it will fail and result in an insert operation.

Of course, if updates are not often expected, it will be exactly the opposite.

This can be seen as complex solution for a simple merge. But it also lets the developer to influence the performance.

Hope this sheds some light!